# How can I monitor bandwidth use between my PC and my phone?

Tags: android, file-transfer, bandwidth, monitoring, smartphone

I've connected a smartphone to my PC using a USB cable, and set my phone to "MTP mode" for file transfer. My PC runs Windows 10 (alas...) and my phone runs MIUI based on Android 6.0.1.

So now, I'm copying a large file (several GBs), and for some reason, Windows is not telling me how the copying is progressing; nor am I seeing the partially-copied file build up on the phone mount.

I want to at least be able to tell that copying is actually going on, by monitoring bandwidth used between the PC and the phone. Can I do that?

Comment: MTP file transfers are pretty bad on Windows. You can opt to use WiFi methods to copy files (FTP server comes to mind).

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22979/drive-letter-for-mtp-connection-under-windows

Answer (score 1):

Use [USBPcap](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/) - USB Packet capture for Windows

Comment: The sounds promising.

Answer (score -1):

No folder explorer normally nothing being transferred. Android is pretty easy to transfer so you may have a bad connection/cable and or your phone requires drivers installed on the computer. Losing the connection between cable and phone is normally the reason you don't see anything being transferred.

Comment: Your first sentence is missing some words, I think.

Comment: I should have typed, if you don't see a folder explorer window open showing transferring or copying data, then most likely nothing is being copied. USB ports are handled through the pci buss and processor, you would need something different than what is actually readily available to "monitor" what is being transferred if anything. if it was wireless, then there are plenty of options out there to monitor traffic. You could try your device manager and see if you clock speeds increase drastically but i ran into something similar with this and it's most likely not reading or copying at all.

Comment: You can edit those changes into your question (and if you do I think I'll upvote it). Actually, even I could do that, but I wanted to let you experience that as a new user. The idea here on StackExchange is that we tweak and improve questions and answers to be as correct and useful as we can make them.